# Applying CSS to second level of bullet points changes tabsetPanel() bullet points in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, user-interface, shiny

This is literally my first time using CSS in my own code, and I ran into trouble in literally the first thing.
I have this very elaborated shiny app (I did it before learning CSS), and I want to use this new skill on it. The first thing I wanted to do was changing the second level of the bullet points. Therefore, the code in the ui is:

```
tags$ul(
  tags$li("1 or 2 tails. Basically, 1 tail is when the hypothesis says that one of the averages will be bigger than the other. And, 2 tails is when the hypothesis says that the averages will be different no matter which one is bigger."),
  tags$li("Grouped or paired."),
  tags$li("Grouped: when there is no special relationship between pairs of data in between the two samples. The sample size (n) for each sample does not require to be the same. For example:"),
  tags$ul(
    tags$li("Comparing the length of 30 leaves taken from the top of a tree and 32 taken from the bottom part of the tree;"),
    tags$li("Comparing male and female height between 30 males and 31 females, not necessarily related;")
  ),
  tags$li("Paired: when there is a pair relationship between samples. Typical for data taken from samples in different conditions of the same subject, or between siblings. The sample size (n) for each sample must be the sam. For example:"),
  tags$ul(
    tags$li("Comparing the length of top and bottom leaves from 30 trees;"),
    tags$li("Comparing male and female height between 30 brothers and 30 sisters;")
  )
)
```

And my CSS is:

```
ul ul li {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

It works fine where I want it to:
[image]
**But**, it does more than that: this code is inside a `tabPanel()` of a `tabsetPanel()` inside a `tabPanel()` in a `navbarPage()`. The thing is: the items in the `tabsetPanel()` also received square bullets. By snooping in the HTML of shiny, I saw this: the `tabsetPanel()` is also a list.

```
# Show a tabset that includes a plot, summary, and
# table view of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
    tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
  )
)
```

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="tabbable tabs-above">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab-7055-1" data-toggle="tab">Plot</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-7055-2" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-7055-3" data-toggle="tab">Table</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-7055-1">
        <div id="plot" class="shiny-plot-output" style="width: 100% ; height: 400px"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-7055-2">
        <pre id="summary" class="shiny-text-output"></pre>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-7055-3">
        <div id="table" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also saw that the `tabsetPanel()` has two classes: `nav` and `nav-tabs`. Therefore, I tried this CSS:

```
ul ul li {
  list-style-type: square;
}

.nav, .nav-tabs {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

At first, I had only one of those, but it didn't. It still doesn't.

A dummy ui that has all the important characteristics, to make things easier, is:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    tabPanel(title = "Just to be here",
             tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel(title = "This seems to be causing some trouble...",
                        tags$ul(
                          tags$li("Text 1"),
                          tags$li("Text 2"),
                          tags$li("Text 3"),
                          tags$ul(
                            tags$li("Text 3.1"),
                            tags$li("Text 3.2")
                          ),
                          tags$li("Text 4"),
                          tags$ul(
                            tags$li("Text 4.1"),
                            tags$li("Text 4.2")
                          )
               )
             )
    )
  )
)
```

My question, then, is: how can I only apply the square bullet points to the actual list, and not to the `tabPanel()`s?

Comment: How exactly do you add the CSS?

Comment: With `includeCSS("www/style.css")` inside my `fluidPage()`.

Answer (score 0):

try to add class to your UL using JS: (you should change the Number "1" in your js code. It depends on how many ul do you have on your page.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].classList.add("newClass");
```

```css
.newClass li{
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
for example: 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab-7055-1" data-toggle="tab">Plot</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-7055-2" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-7055-3" data-toggle="tab">Table</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab-7055-1" data-toggle="tab">Plot</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-7055-2" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-7055-3" data-toggle="tab">Table</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, but shiny's conversion to html is its own; the shiny ui works almost like a translation from its own language (I think of it as half-way between r and html) and the actual html. The class to which `tabPanel()` and `tabsetPanel()` belong are pre-defined, and I can't change them. Also, it would be a pain even if I could.

Comment: I can't add anything... When I call `tabsetPanel()`, it functions as the code I mentioned. Also, I'm not actually writinh HTML, just shiny and css.

Comment: @hamid yes, [you can add js](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/packaging-javascript.html)